# EJB Project doesn't connect to the right Derby database/table

Tags: java, ejb, derby, persistence.xml, entity-bean

having a problem yesterday that i couldn't connect to the derby database (most likely due to persistence.xml issues) I have been guided to modify my persistence.xml so that it contains two additional poperties;

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
```

Having added them I don't get faced with bunch of errors such as `SCHEMA "xx" doesn't exist` or `Unknown entity bean class: class model.Userbay, please verify that this class has been marked with the @Entity annotation.`

Having though everything will be fine now, I realized that isn't the case.. At first i was attempting to obtain one of the rows from the database through the Entity Manager's .find() method. After a while of testing to retrieve the records from the database I though that it might be better to try to insert something into the database and see what happens. Having executed the following line of code;

```
emgr.createNativeQuery("insert into ADRIAN.USERBAY (USER_NAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) values('testts123s', '1', '1', '1', '1')").executeUpdate();
```

I noticed that nothing was inserted into the database... However having tried to execute the .find() to find a primary key i just inserted (testts123s) it has found the record (although in the Data Source Explorer the database's table didn't get populated with this record). Therefore my questions is what could have happened that I was linked to an empty table ?

The following is the code;

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="EJBAuctionv2">
    <!-- <jta-data-source>JDBC/MyDB</jta-data-source> -->
        <class>model.Userbay</class>
        <class>model.Item</class>
        <class>model.Category</class>

        <properties>
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123" />
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="adrian" />
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeededDriver" />
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:C:\Users\Adrian\MyDB;create=true" />
<!-- <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />  -->
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

UserRegistration SessionBean

```
package auction;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.management.Query;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import model.Userbay;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class userRegistrationSB
 */
@Remote @Stateless
public class userRegistrationSB implements userRegistrationSBRemote {

    //@EJB private Userbay user;
    @PersistenceContext(name = "EJBAuctionv2") private EntityManager emgr;
    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public userRegistrationSB() {}

    @Override
    public boolean registerUser(String username, String password, String email,
            String firstname, String lastname) {
        boolean registered = false;

        //emgr.createNativeQuery("insert into ADRIAN.USERBAY (USER_NAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) values('testts123s', '1', '1', '1', '1')").executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("Registering an user with username: " + username);
        Userbay user = emgr.find(model.Userbay.class, username);
        if (user == null) {
            System.out.println("Username doesn't exist.");
            registered = true;
        } else {
            registered = false;
            System.out.println("Username already exists.");
        }

        return registered;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean userExists(String username) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean userMatchesPassword(String username, String password) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Userbay Entity Bean

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;




@Entity @Table (name = "Userbay")
@NamedQuery(name="Userbay.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM Userbay u")
public class Userbay implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name="USER_NAME")
    private String userName;

    private String email;

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Item
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="userbay")
    private List<Item> items;

    public Userbay() {
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public Item addItem(Item item) {
        getItems().add(item);
        item.setUserbay(this);

        return item;
    }

    public Item removeItem(Item item) {
        getItems().remove(item);
        item.setUserbay(null);

        return item;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have any exception after this insert? If you use JPA try to not use native queries if you really don't need it.

Comment: At first insert there wasn't any problem, but the second try it had the following exception (hence why it's commented out now) - org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL140225111513480' defined on 'USERBAY'. P.S. it was used only for testing purposes, and got me to realize that i'm definitely not dealing with the table i would expect.

Comment: So probably generation of id doesn't work. Try to remove this row from database and execute it once again. If everything is OK and you have problem only during second insert it means that you have something wrong with generating ID. Try to change generatedValue strategy for example then.

Comment: I am not sure if you understood my problem though. The problem that bothers me is not inserting. The problem is that I have a database with Userbay table that contains records already, and when I try to find a row with a primary key that does exist it simply returns an empty object. The insertion of stuff was just a test case to see whether it would be inserted into Userbay table (which unfortunately wasn't). I don't even know what table the data got inserted into because I can't visually see it in the Eclipse - Data Source Explorer under any SCHEME.

Comment: So you can't get any results at the beginning (table has some rows), but if you insert some data than you can get results. Is that right? I would suggest to check if you operate on the same database schema than. Btw you have ADRIAN.USERBAY in the insert statement and USERBAY in find query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of messing around with the persistence.xml I fortunately have found an oracle tutorial which  guides to create a new JDBC connection pool and resource for glassfish server, to link the derby database. Having done it, all I needed to put inside the persistence.xml was the JTA data source.

Here's a video where I have done it from the scratch, this time choosing a ClientDriver - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBNB8L49ZQ4

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed that nothing was inserted into the database... However having tried to execute the .find() to find a primary key i just inserted (testts123s) it has found the record.

How exactly did you notice that nothing was inserted into the database? Reading your next sentence it looks like it was.

Regardless

You should avoid inserting records with native SQL. First of all doing this you bypass cache and it may bring you real headache and finally it breaks entire idea of ORM. 
So instead you've better do it with persist method of entity manager.

```
Userbay user = new Userbay();
user.setFirstName("Firstname");
user.setLastName("Lastname");
user.setPassword("password");
user.setEmail("someemail@email.zzz");

emgr.persist(user);
```

As far as you chosen to generate userName it will be generated for you.

Just in case: 
Keep in mind even if you did not open any transaction, the container opened one for you when you called registerUser method. It means your are working in the same transaction until the method ends with all that it implies. Below is an extraction from Oracle tutorial

> The Required attribute is the implicit transaction attribute for all enterprise bean methods running with container-managed transaction demarcation. You typically do not set the Required attribute unless you need to override another transaction attribute. Because transaction attributes are declarative, you can easily change them later.

You may want to read at least these sections for better understanding.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpy.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncih.html

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation, what i meant in "nothing was inserted into database" is that nothing was inserted under my schema ADRIAN - Userbay table. Neither it was inserted into any other schema that exists in the database. Saying that I could retrieve the inserted value testts123s, was true because I was dealing with a table that was empty before i inserted the "testts123s". Therefore my assumption is that a new Table was created that didn't link with the database i wanted it to, and the conclusion is that I don't know what schema/database i'm dealing with.